# Is google OAuth 2.0 for service account part of the OAuth 2.0 standard?

Tags: google-api, oauth-2.0

Google API Authentication has a  OAuth 2.0 for service account
https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ServiceAccount

Is that really part of OAuth 2.0 standard, or just google's own customized schema?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That flow uses the so-called "JSON Web Token (JWT) Profile for OAuth 2.0 Authorization Grants" that is defined in https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7523. The relevant section of that RFC is: https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7523#section-2.1

It is an extension of the core OAuth 2.0 standard grant types defined in https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749 but standardized in the IETF and thus an official part of the OAuth 2.0 eco-system.